# java 8 stream using filter and count

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a array list named employee.

```
List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

I need to get the count of employees whose status is not "2" or null.

```
long count = 0l;
count = employee.stream()
.filter(p->!(p.getStatus().equals("2")) || p.getStatus() == null).count();
```

In the above query getting error like "**lambda expression cannot be used in evaluation expression**", Please help me to resolve this error.

The list employee contains values like

```
 empId  Status
  1       3
  2       4
  3       null
```

If the status column doesn't contains null value it is working fine.

Comment: First of all, check how you are instantiating your ArrayList. If that code is correct it should be updated to "new ArrayList<>()" (note the capital A).

Comment: I initiated the ArrayList in correct syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to `check first if the status is not null then only we would be able to use the equals method on status`, else we will get `NullPointerException`. You also don't need to declare count to `0l`, `count()` will return you 0 when no match is found.

```
List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
// long count = 0l;

// Status non null and not equals "2" (string)
ling count = employee.stream()
    .filter(e ->  Objects.nonNull(e.getStatus()) && (!e.getStatus().equals("2")))
    .count();
```

Comment: Is it better to use "Predicate" instead of writing Lamda expression inside the Filter?

Comment: Yeah, I mean Its good practice in the situation when you have a really big expression or you want to reuse same expression elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work if an Employee has `status = null` is because you are trying to perform the `.equals()` operation on a null object. You should verify that `status` is not equal to null before trying to invoke the .equals() operation to avoid null pointers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find number of project having particular project manager using Java stream API then here you go.

```
public Long listOfProjectWorkingWithPM(){

       return getAllEmployees()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(pm->pm.getProjects().stream())
                .filter(project -> "Robert Downey Jr".equalsIgnoreCase(project.getProjectManager()))
                .count();

    }
```