# how do I create a new char array with only certain elements from another char array using streams in java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an char array, and I want to get the number of the '^' char in that array. so if the array was `'.', '.', '^', '-', '^'` it would return 2. My plan was to make a new array that just contains the '^' char and then get the length of that array. I know this could be easily done with a for loop that loops over the array, but I think it would be cool to use streams as I've just started learning about them and want more practice, and I think it would be hilarious to have a single massive line instead of a few lines for a for loop and if statement. (this code does not need to be readable)

I have tried

```
char[] tentsInRow = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
    .filter(n -> n == '^')
    .mapToObj(m -> arr[m]).toArray();
```

and

```
char[] tentsInRow = new String(getRow(i))
    .chars()
    .mapToObj(n -> (char)n)
    .filter(n -> n.equals('^'))
    .toArray();
```

`getRow(i)` returns a char array, and arr from the first line is the same thing

both of which give me the error: `Required type: char[] Provided: Object[]`

I saw there was a toArray(`IntFunction<a[]> generator`) function I could use that I thought could work, but I wasn't sure how to use it.

Does anyone know how I can convert from an Object array to a char array in this line, or know any other way to do this with streams/lambdas? I can also just do it the boring way with a for loop, just thought this would be cool lol. First post here so go easy

Comment: It is not *hilarious* to have your code in a new line (I'm sure most will agree). To make it readable, I've edited your question, making it multi-line.

Comment: "My plan was to make a new array that just contains the '^' char and then get the length of that array" - why, if you can just count?

Comment: An _hilarious_ way to do it: [java 8 stream using filter and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401251/java-8-stream-using-filter-and-count)

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the number of '^' characters why not use `.count`?

```
long numberOfChars = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> arr[i])
    .filter(n -> n == '^')
    .count();
```

Comment: No need for boxing: `IntStream.range(0, arr.length).filter(i -> arr[i] == '^') .count();`